# Is it possible to download #of votes and the rate of votes an image has in reddit?

Tags: api, reddit

I found an online image **scraper** that can basically download all the imgur images from a subreddit category, can anyone tell me if the reddit API allows me to also add the number of votes and the rate at which the votes are obtained?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. I believe the precise method you're looking for is [GET_info](http://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_api_info) in the api documentation. Alternatively you can use the [json version of a subreddit listing](http://www.reddit.com/r/cats/.json) to get the data. You're looking for `score` and if you want the average score increase per hour, then `created_utc` (avoid created) as well. There are also wrappers for certain languages of Reddit, that can make this easier.